# WPF goes to the top of each pages when navigating/reloading page

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-5

I'm very new to WPF .net 5.0 framework. Every time I navigate to a different page in a frame, it maintains the scroll position instead of going back to the top of the page.  May I know if there is a way to make sure that it goes to the top of the page every time I navigate? Thank you!

this is the xaml

```
<ScrollViewer Height="1000" Width="1000" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="23*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="477*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF5B5858"><Run Language="en-sg" Text="ADD NEW APPLICATION"/></TextBlock>

            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <Border CornerRadius="0,0,30,0" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Frame x:Name="wizardFrame" Content="Frame" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="1002" Margin="0,9,0,471" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

This is the code behind

```
wizardFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new LocationPage1());
```

This is what i use to navigate to different pages in a frame

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new GenerateApplicationNumberPage2());
```

Comment: Can you show part of the XAML where the Frame is declared? Is your Frame inside a ScrollViewer?

Comment: @Arkane hi okay let me edit my post. yes it's inside a scrollviewer!

Comment: [`ScrollViewer.ScrollToTop()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltotop?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the ScrollViewer has no relation to the Frame, so it won't react to the Frame navigating.
In order to fix that, I see two solutions (pick one):

1. You name your ScrollViewer (e.g: mainScroll), and in the code-behind, you subscribe to the `Navigated` event of your Frame, so as to call `ScrollViewer.ScrollToTop()`, as suggested in a comment.

```
// Somewhere in the constructor after InitializeComponent();
wizardFrame.Navigated += (_, __) => mainScroll.ScrollToTop();
```

2. You remove the ScrollViewer from your main page, and add one as the root element in the XAML of each Page (`LocationPage1`, `GenerateApplicationNumberPage2`, and any other page). It will work because you create a new page each time you navigate (which isn't very good for resource management, but this is not the subject here).
   The difference will be that the `TextBlock` with "ADD NEW APPLICATION" will always be visible above the Pages instead of being inside the ScrollViewer.

```
<Page x:Class="Namespace.LocationPage1">
  <ScrollViewer Height="1000" Width="1000">
    <!-- Your page content here -->
  </ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

Comment: I tried the first one and it works thanks!